# Password cannot unlock iPhone, and every several seconds screen turns off

Tags: iphone

I am encountering a very strange situation. After rebooting, I cannot use my password to unlock my iPhone, and the lock screen says "Emergency" at the bottom. At the same time, there is no time display at the lock screen. And every few seconds, the screen will be off. If I connect it into a computer, when the screen is off, the USB connection is also cut. However, it seems I can pick up in-call, and the notification still works. Is there anyone who knows the potential reason?

Comment: "Emergency" is always visible on the passcode entry screen. It allows someone who doesn't know your passcode to make an emergency call or, if you have Medical ID enabled, to access your medical ID.